# QML - Can't get mouse released event when I don't accept mouse pressed event

Tags: events, qml, event-propagation

I would like to dispatch my onPressed event to subsequent objects in my QML tree, (I have indicate mouse.accepted = false and propagateComposedEvents: true ) but I want to keep the onreleased event working on the top level element ..
Here the code :

```
Item {

    width: 200
    height: 200

Rectangle {
    z: 1
    anchors.fill: parent
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        propagateComposedEvents: true
        onPressed: {
            console.log("R1 pressed")
            mouse.accepted = false
        }
        onReleased: {
            console.log("R1 released")
            mouse.accepted = false
        }
    }
}

Rectangle {
    z: 0
    anchors.fill: parent
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        propagateComposedEvents: true
        onPressed: {
            console.log("R2 pressed")
        }
        onReleased: {
            console.log("R2 released")
        }
    }
}

}
```

What I expect to see :

qml: R1 pressed
qml: R2 pressed
qml: R1 released
qml: R2 released

What I get :

qml: R1 pressed
qml: R2 pressed
qml: R2 released

How can I solve that ?

Thanks in advance for your help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `propagateComposedEvents` will not work because its behavior is only defined for composed events, which means one of `clicked`, `doubleClicked` and `pressAndHold`. So when you set `mouse.accepted = false` in R1's `onPressed` handler, this has nothing to do with `propagateComposedEvents`.

Setting `mouse.accepted = false` instead does what it is supposed to do according to the documentation:

> no further events will be sent to this MouseArea until the button is
>   next pressed.

In my opinion, one should only react to mouse inputs on the topmost MouseArea. As long as R1 and R2 completely overlap with each other, you are making R2 something that it simply isn't. In case R1 is smaller than R2 and you want to do something for R2 in R1's handlers, just move the R2 code to a function and call it from both MouseAreas' event handlers. Or just use bindings to both Mouseareas' `pressed` state.

Comment: How do you assume, that `mouse.accepted = false` has nothing to do with `propagateComposedEvents`?. And though it might have been documented that way, the quoted line is false. If you have two `MouseAreas`, the lower handles the `pressAndHold` and the `clicked`-signals, and the upper handles the `pressed` and the `clicked`-signal. The upper propagates composed signals and does not accept the mouse in the `clicked`-event, the lower dos not accept the mouse (in `pressAndHold`). Now the lower gets the *further event* `clicked` though he did not accept the mouse on the same press before.